# flask redirect from closure

Tags: redirect, python-3.x, flask, closures

```
def check_login(func):
    """Check if user is logged in."""
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        if not login_session_test():
            print ("Not logged in - redirect to /login")
            flash ("Well that was wrong. Chicken winner. No more dinner.")
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        print ("Logged in, do what needs to be done.")
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorator

@check_login
@app.route("/sacred/secret/stuff", methods=['GET'])
def funfunfun():
    return "Super fun"
```

It never redirects to `/login` but gives some garbage like page.

Swapping the `@`/closure order yields:

```
AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: decorator
```

I am not yet fully pythonized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your decorator order is incorrect, and you are not copying across the function name to the wrapper function.

Use this order:

```
@app.route("/sacred/secret/stuff", methods=['GET'])
@check_login
def funfunfun():
    return "Super fun"
```

Otherwise the undecorated function is registered for the view.

Use [`@functools.wraps()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) to have various pieces of metadata copied over from the original wrapped function to the wrapper that replaces it:

```
from functools import wraps

def check_login(func):
    """Check if user is logged in."""
    @wraps(func)
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        if not login_session_test():
            print ("Not logged in - redirect to /login")
            flash ("Well that was wrong. Chicken winner. No more dinner.")
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        print ("Logged in, do what needs to be done.")
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorator
```

Routes need an endpoint name, and if you don't specify one explicitly, Flask uses the name of the function (from `functionobj.__name__`). But your decorator wrapper object has the name `decorator`, so if you use the decorator more than once Flask complains that it already has used that endpoint name.

`@functools.wraps()` copies across the `__name__` attribute, so now your decorator wrapper is *also* called `funfunfun`, whereas another decorated route function gets to keep its name too.

Comment: what if my decorator and login test is in another file/module? I get this `werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'login'. Did you mean 'static' instead?`

Comment: @nmz787 as long as that module has been imported, it will work. You can run `flask routes` on the command line to get a full list (there are options to sort them in various ways).  Last but not least: if you are using blueprints you need to prefix the name with the blueprint name and a dot (or just with a dot if you are in a view registered to the same blueprint).